# Line Legend with dashes and thickness not working

Tags: plotting, legending

I am trying to create a line legend with specific dashing and thickness. Here is the code.

```
LineLegend[{{Black, Dashing[Tiny], Thickness[0.005]}, {Black, 
   Dashing[Small], Thickness[0.005]}, {Black, Dashing[Large], 
   Thickness[0.005]}, {Black, Thickness[0.005]}, {Black, 
   Thickness[0.01]}}, {"0.001", "0.01", "1", "10", "100"}]
```

My output is the unevaluated version of my input:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LineLegend[
 {
  Directive[Black, Dashing[Tiny], Thickness[0.005]]
  , Directive[Black, Dashing[Small], Thickness[0.005]]
  , Directive[Black, Dashing[Large], Thickness[0.005]]
  , Directive[Black, Thickness[0.005]]
  , Directive[Black, Thickness[0.01]]
  }
 ,
 {"0.001", "0.01", "1", "10", "100"}
 ]
```

---

**EDIT**

The above solves the problem but a more elegant method is to apply `Directive` to the list of style options that may be provided or are available separately.

```
styleList = {
   {Black, Dashing[Tiny], Thickness[0.005]}, {Black, Dashing[Small], 
    Thickness[0.005]}, {Black, Dashing[Large], 
    Thickness[0.005]}, {Black, Thickness[0.005]}, {Black, 
    Thickness[0.01]}
   };
labelList = {"0.001", "0.01", "1", "10", "100"};

LineLegend[Directive @@@ styleList, labelList]
```

---

Result:

[image]